# PRYMARY KEY must be unique exception while calling update mehtod

Tags: java, sqlite

I am writing a GUI based project using java and SQLite. I created a Table in my SQLite database and using it in my project. there are several column where I made RoomNo as a primary key and gave a default value 111.
The problem is when I try to edit or update data from what you say from jTable and save it to my database it show exception , java.sql.SQLException:PRYMARY KEY must be unique.
I can't find the reason why it shows up. May be the problem is in my code. Here is the code f update method. Please try to help me out to sort out this problem.

```
private void updateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try{
        String value1 = roomNumbertf.getText();
        String value2 = detailtf.getText();
        String value3 = statustf.getText();
        String value4 = billPerDaytf.getText();
        String value5 = clientNametf.getText();
        String value6 = clientAddresstf.getText();
        String value7 = clientMobileNotf.getText();
        String value8 = entryDatetf.getText();
        String value9 = leavingDatetf.getText();

        String sql = "update RoomStatusTable2 set RoomNo='"+value1+"', Details= '"+value2+"', Status='"+value3+"', BillPerDay='"+value4+"',ClientName='"+value5+"', ClientAddress='"+value6+"', ContactNo='"+value7+"', EntryDate='"+value8+"', LeavingDate='"+value9+"'";
        pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstatement.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Information Updated");
        updateTable();
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

// this my SQLite table crate statement 
    CREATE TABLE "RoomStatusTable2" ("RoomNo" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  DEFAULT
    (111) ,"Details" CHAR,"Status" CHAR,"BillPerDay"
    CHAR,"AdvancedBooking" CHAR,"ClientName" CHAR,"ClientAddress"
    CHAR,"ContactNo" CHAR,"EntryDate" CHAR,"LeavingDate" CHAR)

If further information or code is needed to understand where the problem is please comment me.

Comment: Swing tag removed as the problem itself does not involve Swing.

Comment: You are trying to update the primary key (`RoomNo`). You need to make sure it is unique from the other entries already stored, or you will get this exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UPDATE probably should end in `WHERE RoomNo = ...`.
Your update would set all records to have the same RoomNo.

```
String sql = "update RoomStatusTable2 set Details=?, Status=?, BillPerDay=?, "
       + "ClientName=?, ClientAddress=?, ContactNo=?, EntryDate=?, "
       + "LeavingDate=? "
       + "where RoomNo = ?";
try (PreparedStateent pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    pstatement.setString(1, value2);
    pstatement.setString(2, value3);
    pstatement.setString(3, value4);
    pstatement.setString(4, value5);
    pstatement.setString(5, value6);
    pstatement.setString(6, value7);
    pstatement.setString(7, value8);
    pstatement.setString(8, value9);
    pstatement.setInt(9, Integer.parseInt(value1));
    pstatement.executeUpdate();
} // Closes pstatement.
```

Also best make string fields `VARCHAR(40)` or such, VAR indicating that the field is not padded with spaces.

Comment: your suggestion worked perfectly :D . thank you very much.
But now I am facing a new problem. This update method only updated the information in the jTable but not the data in the database! all the information of the table in the database remains same !! will you please suggest me how to solve this?

Comment: The pstatement must be closed. I changed the answer to declare pstatement at the last moment, using try-with-resources which automatically closes the PreparedStatement.

Answer (score 0):

The error itself is descriptive. **PRYMARY KEY must be unique.**

1. Check if the room no value that you are going to update already exists in the database.
2. Since setting default for a column will add the value if it is not provided in the insert statement.

3.You can check the room no value by printing its value and if it is equal to 111 or any other value that is already available in the table, then a different value should be provided.